# error VHDL Synth 8-27 else clause after check for clock not supported VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Me da error en el circuito siguiente [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al intentar hacerlo en VHDL según las siguientes especificaciones:
Cuando la entrada init valga ‘1’ el registro cargará el valor del dividendo. Cuando baje la entrada init, el
registro irá cargando, ciclo a ciclo, la diferencia con el divisor hasta que el valor almacenado sea menor que
dicho divisor. En ese momento, la salida contiene el valor del resto (hasta que se introduzcan nuevos valores
y llegue un nuevo init).

Da error en la línea con !!!! :[Synth 8-27] else clause after check for clock not supported ["E:/pr3/pr3/pr3.srcs/sources_1/new/pr3.vhd":48]
Da también error en la sintetización del módulo PR3 aunque creo q ese es por el error anterior

```
        library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;


entity pr3 is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           init : in STD_LOGIC;
           dividendo : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
           divisor : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
           mod_out : out unsigned(7 downto 0));
end pr3;

architecture RT of pr3 is
signal acum: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal resta: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal comp: std_logic;
signal mux: unsigned(7 downto 0);

begin

    acum_process: process(clk)
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk='1') then
            acum <= "00000000";
        elsif clk'event and clk='0' then
            acum <= mux; !!!!
        end if;
    end process;
    
    mux_process: process(init,resta,dividendo)
    begin
    if (init = '1') then
        mux <= dividendo;
    else 
        mux <= resta;
    end if;
    end process;
    
    resta_process: process(acum,divisor)
    begin
    resta <= acum - divisor;
    end process;
    
    comp_process: process(acum,divisor)
    begin
    if ( acum > divisor) then
        comp <= '1';
    else 
        comp <= '0';
    end if;
    end process;
    
    mod_out<=acum;
    
 end RT;
```

Answer (score 0):

`library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

```
entity pr3 is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           init : in STD_LOGIC;
           dividendo : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
           divisor : in unsigned(7 downto 0);
           mod_out : out unsigned(7 downto 0));
end pr3;

architecture RT of pr3 is
signal acum: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal resta: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal comp: std_logic;
signal mux: unsigned(7 downto 0);
signal load: std_logic;
begin
    load <= init or comp;
    acum_process: process(clk)
    begin
        if (clk'event and clk='1') then
            if(load = '1') then 
                acum <= mux;
                else acum <= acum;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    mux_process: process(init,resta,dividendo)
    begin
    if (init = '1') then
        mux <= dividendo;
    else 
        mux <= resta;
    end if;
    end process;
    
    resta_process: process(acum,divisor)
    begin
    resta <= acum - divisor;
    end process;
    
    comp_process: process(acum,divisor)
    begin
    if ( acum >= divisor) then
        comp <= '1';
    else 
        comp <= '0';
    end if;
    end process;
    
    mod_out<=acum;
    
 end RT;`
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).